# How to analyze pre-post attitudinal data (ordinal) collected from a group of 60 students?

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a survey with 25 items that were administered pre and post an intervention. Each item had four possible responses:

- Not Appealing at all
- Not Appealing
- Somewhat Appealing
- Very Appealing.

The survey was given to a class of 60 students. I have entered the data into SPSS and created a case for each student, with Pre and Post responses. As the data are ordinal in nature it seems like I should use a non-parametric test. Is the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test appropriate?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the answers you get will be quite limited by your design, for which the intervention is totally confounded with the passage of time.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that your dependent variable will be a composite of some or all of the 25 items.
If this is the case, your composite variable can take

$$kc - c + 1$$
categories, where $k$ is the number of items, and $c$ is the number of categories. Thus, if you formed a composite based on the 25 items, your scale would take on $25 \times 4 - 4 + 1 = 97$ different values. In most cases, researchers treat such scales as numeric variables. This of course is an assumption, but I generally find it a useful assumption and certainly more useful than using non-parametric tests.

Thus, a paired-samples t-test would generally be appropriate assuming at least a reasonable spread of scores on the scale.

#### Related questions

- [What are good basic statistics to use for ordinal data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-are-good-basic-statistics-to-use-for-ordinal-data)
- [Under what conditions should Likert scales be used as ordinal or interval data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10/under-what-conditions-should-likert-scales-be-used-as-ordinal-or-interval-data?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you Jeromy Anglim for your response and the links to "related questions." They were very helpful.

I worked on computing the Wilcoxon signed-rank stats option in SPSS and have prepared a table with the T, z, p, and r (effect size). I will now try out the paired-samples t-test to see what the results look like.

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy summing several items (or taking the mean or otherwise using the arbitrary codes to create a composite score), you already assumed more than merely ordinal measurement so you might as well go for the t-test.

On the other hand, if you want to be absolutely strict in treating your data as ordinal, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is not particularly helpful because it is based on a ranking of the *differences* between pre-test and post-test scores, which means assuming than $2 - 1$ is the same as $4 - 3$ and therefore than the codes you assigned to each response have some meaning beyond their order (see [Is ordinal or interval data required for the Wilcoxon signed rank test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47168/is-ordinal-or-interval-data-required-for-the-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test)).

In fact, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is most useful with measures that are continuous and interval-level but have poorly behaving distributions (skew, mixtures of normal distributions, etc.) In that case, it can have much better power than the t-test. So you might want to consider using it with scales' scores (composite of several items), not as a way to avoid assuming that your data are measured on an interval scale but to increase power.

If you are looking for a simple alternative, item-by-item sign tests would avoid any such assumption. However, with a relatively small sample, many items and very few categories, ties are going to be a problem, multiple testing issues, power and interpretation too.

All of these approaches (and some others) can be defensible but the popular notion that interval means t-test and ordinal means “non-parametric” is not a good way to guide analysis.